# How to join table that contains no data yet with sqlite

Tags: node.js, sqlite, join

I am trying to join two tables: users and favourites. There is a possibility that a user has no favourites yet and when I tried to INNER JOIN the two I didn't get back the user without any favourites. Is there any way to join even if the second table has no data for that user?

I created the users tabel with the following code:

```
db.run(`CREATE TABLE Users(
            UserId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
            Name TEXT NOT NULL,
            Password TEXT NOT NULL,
            Phone VARCHAR,
            Email TEXT,
            RestaurantId INTEGER,
            FOREIGN KEY(RestaurantId) REFERENCES Restaurants(RestaurantId))`, (err) => {
                if(err) {
                    console.error(err.message);
                } else {
                    //insert some values
                    var insert = 'INSERT INTO Users (Name, Password, Phone, Email, RestaurantId) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)';
                    db.run(insert, [
                        'Liam', 
                        'blabla',
                        '+32412345678',
                        'email@email.com',
                        1
                    ]);
                }
            }
        );
```

And the favourites table with:

```
db.run(`CREATE TABLE Favourites(
            FavouriteId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
            UserId INTEGER NOT NULL,
            RestaurantId INTEGER NOT NULL,
            FOREIGN KEY(UserId) REFERENCES Users(UserId),
            FOREIGN KEY(RestaurantId) REFERENCES Restaurants(RestaurantId))`, (err) => {
                if(err) {
                    console.error(err.message);
                } else {
                    //insert some values
                    var insert = 'INSERT INTO Favourites (UserId, RestaurantId) VALUES (?, ?)';
                    db.run(insert, [
                        1,
                        1
                    ]);
                }
            }
        );
```

There is no problem with the data that exists in the table that was generated after these inserts. The problem only exists when a new user without favourites gets added to the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for LEFT JOIN. Take a look at the documentation: https://www.w3resource.com/sqlite/sqlite-left-join.php.

LEFT JOIN returns all the records on the left side of the join, with the matched records from the right side.

Comment: I tried that already, if I do a left join then I get UserId=null because that doesn't exist yet in the Favourites table

Comment: If your user exists in the users table, doing: SELECT * FROM users u LEFT JOIN favorites v ON .... should work fine, even with no records in favorites. Can you post your query, it might shed some light on your problem?

Comment: yeah I get the user but the UserId gets overwritten bu the null value in Favourites

Comment: I found that if I specify what tables I want to select and give them an alias it works

Comment: Well, yes. If your columns have the same name and you do not alias them, you might get problems

Comment: That was indeed the main issue! Thanks for your answer